# What conventions will RPG.SE members be attending?

Tags: discussion, convention

Convention season is upon us.

What conventions will you be attending? Is anyone hosting games at any of these conventions? Do you want to meet up with other RPG.SE users while you are there?

If there is interest in specific conventions maybe we could do a more formal meetup or a chat room dedicated to folks communicating about a specific con.

EDIT: low and behold Mr. Atwood has posted on the [stackoverflow blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/supporting-community-conferences/) on this very thing.

Answer (score 3):

### GenCon 2011

I would be happy to meet any of the great RPG.SE folks I have grown to know if anyone else will be at the big gig!

**EDIT**: It was a great con - sorry I didn't meet any of you there!

Comment: A few of my buddies are going but I couldn't make the trip this year. Keeping my fingers crossed for 2012!

Answer (score 3):

### GenCon 2012

I will be at GenCon 2012 - will anybody else from RPG.SE be there?

Comment: I will — I'll be wearing the colors on at least one day. Are you doing any of the scheduled events?

Comment: @Jadasc - RPG.SE events? Or any of the events? I didn't know there were RPG.SE events. I'll be wearing my shirt one day too. I tend to frequent the indie games on demand room and the boardgame rooms for the wee hours. Hope to see you there!

Comment: I'll be there too wearing the colors probably on Thursday.

Answer (score 2):

After years of hearing about **Dragon Con 2011**, I may very well attempt the trek to Atlanta providing I have no other commitments that weekend.

If I end up making it out there, I'd love to meet up with some folks, but again, it's a big "if" if I can even make it out that way.

Comment: I may try to be there on Friday or Saturday.

Comment: @waxeagle If y'all are sure about going, lets see if we can't get you set up with something to hand out...

Comment: @C.Ross need to talk to the wife a bit more, not certain yet. I will try to firm up my plans this weekend

Answer (score 1):

[Metatopia 2011](http://www.dexposure.com/m2011.html): A new Double Exposure convention for game designers and alpha testers. I already did most of my other conventioning for 2011. (Dreamation, Dexcon, and I-CON have already gone by for this year.)

Comment: How did this turn out? And are you going again this year?

Comment: I thought it was great. =) I got to playtest Fortune Cookie Kung Fu, got some great feedback, and tried out other people's new games. I met a couple of big RPG guys like Fred Hicks (Evil Hat) and Ken Hite, and dramatically expanded my Google+ contact list. They also have a good panel track for game designers. I am planning to go again this year.

Answer (score 1):

## Pacificon 2012

http://pacificongameexpo.com/blog/

It's one of the biggest west coast gaming conventions, held in Santa Clara, California this year (just outside San Jose).

(Though I'm mainly going to promote my latest board game.)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to go to [consternation](http://www.consternation.org/), the latest British Roleplaying Society Convention, but as normal now I am a family man there will not be time this year :(

Answer (score 0):

[Ropecon](http://ropecon.fi) and [Tracon](http://tracon.fi), both in Finland, pretty much every year. I generally game master something, and may give a talk on some subject, as well. If anyone happens to visit Finland at the relevant times, please do tell.

(Both of the websites have material in English. Find a small flag or text such as "In English" and click it.)